# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error for upgrading spring boot to 2.6.6 from 2.2.5_release

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and would like to upgrade to 2.6.6
it can be built but when trying to run , getting error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:228)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at ca.x.x.api.CheckoutApiApplication.main(CheckoutApiApplication.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

In my pom file I have :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2021.0.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
```

And here is my dependency tree:

```
     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-brave:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-slf4j:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-messaging:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-rpc:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-streams:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpclient:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpasyncclient:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-jms:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-mongodb:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.aws:brave-propagation-aws:jar:0.21.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-metrics-micrometer:jar:2.16.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.16.3:compile
[INFO] |           \- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.23.2:compile
validation:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- net.jodah:typetools:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-deployer:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-deployer-resource-maven:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.25:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.3:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  \- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-connector-basic:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-transport-file:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-transport-http:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:runtime
[INFO] |        |     +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-transport-wagon:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO] |        |        \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO] |        |           \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.12.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] |              +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] |              \- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.13.1:compile


SNAPSHOT:compile
    [INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:runtime
    [INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:6.4.0.jre8:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-test:jar:3.1.3:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:3.1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:3.1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.6:test
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:test
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support:jar:3.2.2:test
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-verifier:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-spec:jar:3.1.1:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-spec-java:jar:3.1.1:test
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- dk.brics.automaton:automaton:jar:1.11-8:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-spec-groovy:jar:3.1.1:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:test
    [INFO] |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:jar:2.20.0:test
    [INFO] |  +- com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert:jsonassert:jar:0.6.1:test
    [INFO] |  +- com.rackspace.eclipse.webtools.sourceediting:org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor:jar:2.1.100:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- edu.princeton.cup:java-cup:jar:10k:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:4.6:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.5.9:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:jar:2.5.9:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.5.9:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.5.9:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
    [INFO] |  +- com.github.jknack:handlebars:jar:4.1.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.5:test
    [INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
    [INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:2.0.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:2.0.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:2.0.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:2.0.2:test
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:test
    [INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
    [INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:2.0.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:2.0.2:test
    [INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0:test
    [INFO] |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.11.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.2.12:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |     \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
    [INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
    [INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
    [INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.3.1.Final:compile
    [INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:jar:1.3.1.Final:provided
    [INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.10:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.6:compile
    [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.5:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.6.6:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.6:test
    [INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.0.0:test
    [INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4:test
    [INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:6.8.8:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
    [INFO] |  \- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.27:test
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:runtime
    [INFO] |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.18:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-serialization:jar:1.5.18:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.9.5:runtime
    [INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:jar:1.5.18:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:jar:1.5.18:compile
    [INFO] |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams:jar:1.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:jar:3.1.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.6.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.6.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.7.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
```

I searched a lot and tried many solutions but no success .
Should I add spring-core or spring context separately in pom file ?
How can I check which spring-core is matched for spring boot 2.6.6?
Any advice to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is indeed with spring-core jar.If you see the version of spring-core that is shown in dependency tree its 5.2.4.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup.html

If we see this javadoc, this class is since 5.3 spring framework version, so its not found.

I would recommend you to add starter dependencies in your pom.
eg:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and so on. These dependencies will then be fully available in compile classpath + fetch all transitive dependencies.

Eg same graph for me looks like:

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator -> 2.6.3
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.6.3
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.6.3
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.15
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.15
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.15
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.15
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.15
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.15 (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.15 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.15 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.15 (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.15
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.15 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.6.3
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.6.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.6.3
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.10
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.10
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32 -> 1.7.33
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.33
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.33
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.33
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.15 (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.29
....
```

Note: Even spring-web,data jpa dependencies fetch spring core so do not worry, just ensure you add them in pom to get things running.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I added those but still have the same issue and still it loads the 5.2.4 , I will add my pom as well

Comment: If I have the third-party lib that uses the old spring lib , how can I override those old ones?